# Mandatory sub-arguments for particular value of conditional arguments -Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I need to parse additional arguments depending on the value of a conditional argument ('--name').
I don't want to handle it with 'if statements'.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--name", required = True, choices = ['a','b','c'])
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.name== 'a':
    parser.add_argument( add some mandatory arguments here )

if args.name== 'b':
    parser.add_argument( add some mandatory arguments here )

if args.name== 'c':
    parser.add_argument( add some mandatory arguments here )

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I got a similar question on this [Python argparse conditional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078181/python-argparse-conditional-arguments) but the solution doesn't help me.

**Note**: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: `subparsers` is the the mechanism that `argparse` provides for this - but `name` has to be a positional argument, not a flagged one.

Comment: In your sketched code, use `parse_known_args` to read `--name`.  That way it won't complain about the additional strings.  But a good alternative to conditional `add_argument` is to accept all of the possible flagged arguments, and then test for required values after parsing.  And with good choices of defaults, you might not even need to require certain arguments.

Comment: I have tested a variation on `add_subparsers` that creates a flagged (`optionals`) argument rather than the normal positional.   That is, one that accepts '--name a' instead of 'a'.  But it's not thoroughly tested, and not something that I've seen anyone else propose on SO.