# Python argparse; if argument 1 not present, how to continue and set required next arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have 3 arguments in my python script. Two are required for running the script and argument 1 shows only a list of options. 
I want that if argument 1 is set, that argument 2 and 3 are not required anymore, and if argument 1 is not used, that argument 2 and 3 are required.

The arguments are as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--1", help="list of options", action="store_true", default=False)
parser.add_argument("--2", help="level", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--3", help="folder", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I tried it with the following command:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--1", help="list of options", action="store_true", default=False)
parser.add_argument("--2", help="level)
parser.add_argument("--3", help="folder")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.1:
    print('list of options')
    sys.exit()
if not args.1:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--1", help="list of options", action="store_true", default=False)
    parser.add_argument("--2", help="level", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--3", help="folder", required=True)
```

But the problem than is that if the user only set option 2 (or only option 3), that the script continues, instead of having both options 2 and 3 required.
Is it possible in Python to first test for option 1 and, if this option is not set, continue to test for option 2 and 3, and set these two as required?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want (you'll have to have an extra command like `./script.py list` or `./script.py run --2 level --3 folder`) -- but have you looked at [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)?

Comment: The simplest thing is to test the values yourself, after parsing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857603/mandatory-sub-arguments-for-particular-value-of-conditional-arguments-python-2

Comment: I have worked out a way of changing the `required` values using a custom Action class.  Not too messy as custom Actions go, but still a bit advanced.  And the `help/usage` won't give any hint of this special requirement.  It's one thing to perform mutual-interaction tests on the arguments, it's quite another to explain things clearly to your users.